# how do i check the rules assign on check constraint on oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi currently im getting unique constraint error.
when i check the table there are check constraint assigned to few columns but i dont know what are the rules assigned to those check constraint.
is there anyway i can check what rules has been assigned to those check constraint?

Thank you

Comment: HI you could check in the following Oracle views , select * from USER_CONSTRAINTS;
or select * from all_CONSTRAINTS; and see the constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i dont know **what are the rules** assigned to those check constraint

These are stored in `search_condition` column of `user_constraints` view.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id      number constraint pk_test primary key,
  3     deptno  number constraint fk_test_dept references dept (deptno),
  4     salary  number constraint ch_sal check (salary > 100)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_type, search_condition
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                C SEARCH_CONDITION
------------------------------ - ----------------------------------------
CH_SAL                         C salary > 100            --> here it is
PK_TEST                        P
FK_TEST_DEPT                   R

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
  id NUMBER(10),
  name VARCHAR2(50),
  age NUMBER(3),
  CONSTRAINT age_gt_zero CHECK (age > 0)
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'C';
```

Output:

| CONSTRAINT_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| AGE_GT_ZERO | AGE_GT_ZERO |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/clxw7O2v)